# Alt + Tab to show all instances of an application?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, gnome-shell

How can I 'flatten' <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycle to show all application windows?

For example, before this update, you would just continue <kbd>Alt</kbd> tabbing until you reached the required application window. However, if I have  windows of an app, I have to get to it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, press arrow down key and then choose between instances.

Is it possible to configure alt-tabbing so that it skips that extra 'arrow down' step? Is it possible without 3rd party app?